# Корректный перенос состояния между вызовами в Java

Tags: java

Часто встречаюсь с задачей переноса состояния между различными последовательными вызовами, которые решаются банальной итерацией в синхронном выполнении и которые делают очень больно в асинхронном. Например, в случае написания API-клиента может потребоваться передавать, какая это по счету попытка выполнения запроса, чтобы при превышении предела оборвать тщетные попытки и просто вернуть исключение. Синхронная версия может выглядеть так (пример упрощен):

```
HttpResponse execute(HttpRequest request) throws TimeoutException {
    Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.createStarted();
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_RETRIES; i++) {
        if (timer.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) > REQUEST_TIMEOUT) {
            throw new TimeoutException();
        }
        try {
            return tryExecute(request);
        } catch (ConnectionException e) {
            // cycle one more time
        }
    }
    throw new UnreachableHostException();
}
```

В случае с асинхронной начинается боль: в тело метода так или иначе должны попасть номер попытки и таймер выполнения. Здесь я вижу два решения (и они оба *так себе*):

1. Сделать отдельный приватный класс состояния, в котором передавать все необходимое, и обновлять / пересоздавать его на каждый вызов:

   ```
   CompletableFuture<HttpResponse> execute(HttpRequest request, State state) {
       if (state.getTimer().elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) > REQUEST_TIMEOUT) {
           CompletableFuture<HttpResponse> synchronizer = new CompletableFuture<>();
           synchronizer.completeExceptionally(new TimeoutException());
           return synchronizer;
       }
       if (state.getAttempt() >= MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
           CompletableFuture<HttpResponse> synchronizer = new CompletableFuture<>();
           synchronizer.completeExceptionally(new UnreachableHostException());
           return synchronizer;
       }
       return tryExecute(request)
           // о да, мы идем прямо в ад. прошу не обращать 
           // внимание на саму сложность конструкции
           .handle((result, throwable) -> {
               if (result != null) {
                   return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result);
               }
               if (throwable instanceof ConnectionException) {
                   state.setAttempt(state.getAttempt() + 1);
                   return execute(request, state);
               }
               CompletableFuture synchronizer = new CompletableFuture<>();
               synchronizer.completeExceptionally(throwable);
               return synchronizer;
           })
           .thenCompose(f -> f);
   }
   ```
2. Сделать отдельный приватный одноразовый класс запроса, в который поместить сам метод и необходимое состояние в виде полей. Выглядеть это будет примерно так же (только обращения вместо `state` будут идти к `this`), поэтому сам код я приводить не буду.

Оба подхода ужасно выглядят, требуют безумное количество кода и не импонируют мне. То, что итеративная версия выглядит так просто, подсказывает мне, что я просто не очень хорошо влез в парадигму программирования, и что-то недопонимаю. Как правильно передавать состояние в таких вызовах?

Comment: Если правильно понял задачу, то вынести всю логику с повторами/кэшированием в менеджер, который ведет очередь, запускает/перезапускает запросы если надо. А самому запросу информация о том, сколько раз он запускался ни к чему...

Comment: @YuraIvanov честно говоря, не очень хорошо понимаю, как в таком случае должен выглядеть менеджер. Он должен держать у себя мапу <запрос, контест>, которую постоянно дергать?

Comment: угу, типа того. На самом деле у вас должен быть кто-то кто запускает эти execute и кто-то кто уже держит для каждого запроса state'ы, пусть это будет менеджер. например, на вход поступает runnable, менеджер запускает task в executor'e, получает ответ, положительный или исключение, повторяет запрос если надо... Например, так работает volley: кэширует запросы, делает retry, наружу приходит один колбэк.

Comment: @etki Не рассматриваете возможность использования модели акторов? Очень удобная модель многопоточности, легко укладывается в голове и оперативной памяти. Например, в фреймворке Akka, реализующем модель акторов, таймауты, ретраи, счётчики попыток, экспоненциальный фоллбэк - очень легко и органично.

Comment: @iTollu в стэндэлон-библиотеке?

Comment: @etki Если об Akka - то да, она распространяется как набор библиотек ( http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/java.html ). Доступны API для Scala и для Java

Comment: @iTollu по-другому: мне в библиотеке HTTP-клиента стоит тянуть и запускать акку целиком?

Comment: Если речь о клиентской библиотеке - наверно, не стоит. Акка запускает систему акторов. Предполагается, что она будет одна на весь рантайм. Соответственно, тогда её преимущества можно использовать и при реализации ядра (бизнес-логики), и при реализации инфраструктурных адаптеров.  Если речь идёт о том, чтобы сделать библиотеку, поддерживающую переподключение (как для RabbitMQ) - то, конечно, засовывать систему акторов внутрь неё не стоит. Но альтернативой может быть клиентская либа, не отрабатывающая проблемы сама, а генерирующая об этом достаточное количество событий или коллбэков.

Comment: В конце концов, мы же не должны создавать у разработчиков, использующих эту библиотеку, иллюзию того, что сетевое взаимодействие быстро, безотказно и беспроблемно. Задача клиентской библиотеки - безопасным и удобным образом обернуть API. А уже использовать её можно в различных моделях конкурентности и отказоустойчивости, на усмотрение разработчика.

Comment: @iTollu я вас и подвожу к тому, что обсуждается не приложение, а библиотека. Я не стремлюсь где-то создать какую-то иллюзию, здесь вопрос стоит только об автоматических повторах запросов в тех ситуациях, которые захочет конечный пользователь, потому что спихивать на него эти проблемы как раз-таки путь worse is better.

Comment: посмотрите в сторону RxJava, оно как раз под это заточено

Comment: А может стоит это предоставить серверу, и указать правила для передачи запросов непосредственно в приложение? Обычно у того же Апаче или IIS есть механизмы для ограничения количества запросов.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov каким образом сервер будет совершать повторы не дошедших до него запросов?

Comment: А зачем? У вас задача отсеивать  превышение предела.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov у меня задача повторять запросы и считать количество совершенных, помимо прочего. Поэтому повторюсь: каким образом совершенно чужой сервер мне в этом поможет?

Comment: Если совершенно чужой, то никак.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov бинго

Comment: У вас свой HttpClient? Или обычный, апачевский? Почему не используете `setHttpRequestRetryHandler`?

Comment: @vp_arth не апачевский (по умолчанию), там вообще используется интерфейс и через адаптер можно воткнуть любой. И дело не в том, что конкретно здесь http клиент, дело в переносе состояния между вызовами, которое может быть далеко не только в http клиентах, поэтому я прошу не сводить все к конкретному кейсу, как уже раз десять сделали выше.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно переносить такую логику в менеджер, который и будет хранить состояние.

Пример для Java7/8: [AsyncRetryExecutor](https://github.com/nurkiewicz/async-retry/blob/master/src/main/java/com/nurkiewicz/asyncretry/AsyncRetryExecutor.java) на базе [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
RetryExecutor executor = new AsyncRetryExecutor(scheduler)
    .retryOn(ConnectionException.class)
    .withExponentialBackoff(500, 2)     //500ms х2 каждую попытку
    .withMaxDelay(10_000)               //10 сек макс.
    .withUniformJitter()                // +/- 100ms случайно
    .withMaxRetries(10);

final CompletableFuture<HttpResponse> future = executor.getWithRetry(() ->
        new HttpResponse(...)
);

future.thenAccept(response ->
        System.out.println("response received")
);
```

Comment: Окей, а какое устройство внутри менеджера?